# Processing when ModalOperator has already been executed

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to make an add-on using the Timer of ModalOperator.

I want to prevent the same ModalOperator from running if the ModalOperator was already running.

What should I do now?

https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_timer.py

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            # change theme color, silly!
            color = context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
            color.s = 1.0
            color.h += 0.01

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by checking whether the timer has been set before. Unfortunately the example has a little confusing mistake. `self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)` does not assign a value to the class attribute `_timer` as declared at the beginning of the class. Instead it creates an instance attribute named `_timer`. You can see this by adding the following two lines after the assignment:

```
print(f"self._timer = {self._timer}")
print(f"ModalTimerOperator._timer = {ModalTimerOperator._timer}")
```

The first `print()` will show the the content of the instance attribute, the second `print()` the content of the class attribute. If you try this you will see that the class attribute will always be `None`, it's never assigned the value. Therefore this needs to be fixed before you add the check to see if a timer has been previously assigned.

One way of solving this, is making all reads and writes happen to the class attribute by replacing `self` with `ModalTimerOperator` and thereby actually using the class attribute declared at the beginning. Then you can check in `execute` whether the `timer` is `None` and only then add a new timer when it is. Set `timer` to `None` when the modal operator is canceled.

**Update:** In order to follow the [naming convention](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) I've renamed `ModalTimerOperator` to `WM_OT_modal_timer_operator`.

```
import bpy


class WM_OT_modal_timer_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            # change theme color, silly!
            color = context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
            color.s = 1.0
            color.h += 0.01

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        if WM_OT_modal_timer_operator.timer is None:
            WM_OT_modal_timer_operator.timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
            wm.modal_handler_add(self)
            print("Adding new timer")
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self.timer)
        WM_OT_modal_timer_operator.timer = None

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_modal_timer_operator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_modal_timer_operator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

If you register the operator and then run it multiple times through <kbd>F3</kbd> or *Edit > Operator Search*, you will see that a new timer is only added when there hasn't been a previous one or it has been canceled.

Comment: You could also use `type(self)` instead of `ModalTimerOperator`, which makes refactoring a bit quicker in case you decide to rename the class. Not sure what's considered more pythonic.